# Fitting piecewise function in gnuplot

Tags: function, gnuplot, bounds, curve-fitting, fitbounds

I want to fit multiple bounded functions in gnuplot, fitting the bound values as well.

For example:

```
f(x)=a          (for x < b)

f(x)=a+(x-b)**c (for x > b)

fit f(x) 'data.dat' via a,b,c
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm... interesting.  Why don't you try the following:

```
f(x)=(x<b)?a:a+(x-b)**c
fit f(x) 'data.dat' via a,b,c
```

*tested by @george (see comments).  Thanks george!*

Comment: just had to try that - yes it works.. I expected some horrible fit but it actually did good for some data I made up..

Comment: @george -- I'm glad it works.  I've been meaning to put together a little test, I just hadn't gotten around to it.